# Acceso bloqueado: [my_project] no completó el proceso de verificación de Google

Tags: api, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

Pues estoy tratando de hacer un envio de correos con la ayuda de google API, pero al momento en que coloco mi `OAuth Client ID` y el `OAuth Client Secret` me tira este mensaje diciendome que no tengo acceso a mi propio proyecto?

### Tengo mis configuraciones de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis claves generadas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con mis credenciales colocadas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y en la página para autorizar a gmail:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando le doy en "Authorize API", seleccionando mi correo(**Dueño** del proyecto), me tira este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien sabe qué pasos me etoy saltando?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y no he podido solucionarlo. A que te refieres con que debo añadir las APIS. Cuales APIS? y donde encuentro esto?

Comment: @Christian esta parte queda obsoleta para acceder a tu cuenta, en tu configuración de tu cuenta de gmail, en la parte de seguridad hay una sección que te genera una contraseña auxiliar, esa sería tu contraseña para acceder desde otros lugares. OJO esto es inseguro, mejor hazlo con una cuenta que no sea personal

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de solucionar este mismo problema para mi proyecto. Debes ir a la sección "Pantalla de consentimiento" y en el punto 2 (Permisos), Debes añadir las APIs que vas a utilizar en tu aplicación, además de que estas APIs deben estar habilitadas previamente.

Por último, para asegurar que te funcione, puedes agregar tu correo en la lista de usuarios de prueba.

Con estos pasos ya no tuve este problema. Avísame cómo te va. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso Funciono al publicar la Aplicación

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNu56.png

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/399643)